# Weid Pagination layout and double icons in datatables and bootstrap integration

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am trying to fix some shape issues when I integrate Datatables with Bootstrap

**To be considered:** I do not use any CDN. All external files are imported in my project manually.

**Issue 1: Double Icons**

I see both JQuery and Bootstrap icons in DataTable sorting area. I can fix this removing the following images from my project:

- sort_asc.png
- sort_both.png
- sort_desc.png
- ...

However, if I do so this will trigger an error in the developer console which tells that those files are missing. I would like to have only the bootstrap ones.

**Issue 2: Pagination**

The pagination icons are not next to each other I would like to have something like the image below:

[image]

**Issue 3: Alignment**

The header labels do not align with the row labels. Rows are a bit on the left. Why?

I have created this jsfiddle for your consideration

https://jsfiddle.net/d6rw4xyx/

This is how I have initialized my DT

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#table').DataTable( {
        renderer: "bootstrap"
    } );
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Try to remove jquery.dataTables.min.css from external libs. It seems that this lib overrides bootstrap classes

Comment: ohh yeeeessss. This solved all three issues at once. It seems also to work without `renderer: "bootstrap"`. Should I leave it there or is it better if I pull it out?

Comment: sorry but I'm not sure about that. I was looking at this example https://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap-simple.html and just compared to your jsfiddle.

Comment: well in the source code it does not appear :) Thank you very much. if you answer I am going to accept thankssss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove jquery.dataTables.min.css from external libs. It seems that this lib overrides bootstrap classes. See the example [here](https://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap-simple.html)